# Understanding how to integrate Backbone JS with a Python crud app

Tags: javascript, python, django, backbone.js, frontend

I'm building a crud app using Python and Django. I want to use Backbone to access the api, grab the user data and render it accordingly. I'm new to Backbone and had some questions on a high level:

1) What advantage does Backbone provide that I can't do with regular Javascript?

2) I understand that Models and Collections make up the M in the MVC layer in Backbone, but lets say I have a User model written in Python, would I still need Models and Collections in Backbone or just Collections? Are the Models of Backbone the same as the Models in Python?

I need help understanding the difference and uses in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone is a really nice frontend framework that allows you to work with websockets and the like.

Backbone is a frontend framework that does not need "direct" access to the db. It will work with django models using either django rest framework, or websockets(redis, tornado, etc.). Backbone models can be just representations of data from the backend, it's how backbone deals with the serialized data passed from the server. It's MCRVT (Model collection routes views template).

TL:DR; Backbone models are representations of restful resources.